# Backspace key in Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-outlook-2010, keymap

I use Outlook 2010 on Windows 7.  I'd like the backspace key to delete the current message, and not jump to a random message or folder.

Details: when viewing the list of messages in a mail folder, I can delete the current one by hitting the delete key or Control-D.  Backspace is strange - it changes the "active context", i.e. what message, folder, calendar, etc. is being viewed.

Backspace := the key two above enter, which says "backspace" on it, and has an arrow pointing to the left.

Delete := lower-left of 6 keys to the right of the main block of keys on standard 101 keyboard.

It would be very nice to map backspace to delete the current item, but I can't find a way to re-map / customize the keyboard.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I suggest you edit your post or it may get closed.

Comment: Just use the delete key.